# How to show contents of ViewData in a window on postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to show the content of ViewData, which holds string in my case, on a modal window.
For this, I am using following code in my view.

```
<h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>
<form runat = "server">
<div onload = "poponload('<%=ViewData["sample"].ToString()%>')">
  <input type="submit" value="show" id="submitBtn"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
  function poponload(msg) {
    alert(msg.toString().length);
    if (msg.toString().length > 0) {
      my_window = window.open("",
  "mywindow1", "status=1,width=350,height=150");
      my_window.document.write(msg.toString());
    }
  }
</script>
</form>
```

The controller contains simple action methods as follows.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
      ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
      return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
    {
      ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
      ViewData["sample"] = "My name is kaps";
      return View();
    }
```

I want to show the contents of ViewData["sample"] using Window.open().
But this code is unable to show me the desired output. Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a javascript library such as JQuery. There are many modal popup plugins that make this sort of thing very simple.

One of my favourites is [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) by Eric Martin. Below is an example of how this could be used to display ViewData.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#sample").modal();
     });        
</script>
<div id="sample"><%=ViewData["key"]%></div>
```

**Edit:**

To use window.open see below. However this is not a modal popup as it exists in a new browser window. This is likely to get blocked by popup blockers so I would not do it this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var url = "<%= ViewData["key"].ToString() %>";
         window.open(url, "DescriptiveWindowName",
              "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
     });        
</script>
```

From the [mozilla developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open)

> How can I tell when my window was blocked by a popup blocker?
>   With the built-in popup blockers of Mozilla/Firefox and Internet Explorer 6 SP2, you have to check the return value of window.open(): it will be null if the window wasn't allowed to open. However, for most other popup blockers, there is no reliable way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how can I do this using Window.open()?

Answer (score 0):

Is the javascript running? If not, try to put the method in the jquery ready method.

Something like:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      alert(msg.toString().length);
      if (msg.toString().length > 0) {
         my_window = window.open("",
           "mywindow1", "status=1,width=350,height=150");
           my_window.document.write(msg.toString());
   });
</script>
```

If you explain a little better what happens, it would be easier to give a solution. I'm not able to run the code here, so more info is needed.

Comment: The script is not running. I wrapped the script inside ready(). But still it isn;t working.

Comment: Have you included a reference to jquery.js? This is needed to get $(document).ready working.

Comment: Where to add that & how to add? On master page?

Comment: You can add it either in the masterpage or in the aspx. Depending on if you want to use jquery everywhere or not. Add something like:
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> to your file.

Comment: I have MVC2 RC2 installed. And my scripts folder contains jquery-1.4.1.js. Am I supposed to add this?

Comment: Yes, that's just a newer version. I only have MVC 1.0 installed here, and haven't bothered to upgrade jquery yet.

Answer (score 0):

A `div` does not support the `onload` attribute.

move your code to the `body` tag instead.

```
<body onload = "poponload('<%=ViewData["sample"].ToString()%>')">
```

Comment: I don;t want to use body tag. Can;t I do this without changing the default page contents of MVC view.